# Objective-C to Swift : Pass Completion Handler

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am trying to convert the following to swift but am not sure how to handle the parameters.

```
- (void)requestDiscoverabilityPermission:(void (^)(BOOL discoverable)) completionHandler{}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it would look like e.g. this:

```
    func requestDiscoverabilityPermission(completionHandler: (discoverable: Bool!) -> ()?) {
        // ...
    }
```

*NOTE: you can play with the optional, non-optional parameters freely in your final code.*

Answer (score 1):

```
func requestDiscoverabilityPermissionWithCompletion(completion:(discoverable: Boolean) -> Void){}
```

[reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/interactingwithobjective-capis.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-XID_34)